# What is the correct way to configure the SendMail SMART_HOST option to perform MX lookups?

Tags: email-server, sendmail

I think this question is related to [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/215010/sendmail-smart-host-not-working) but I feel that it's different enough to warrant a separate post.

I currently have my Sendmail server configured to send to a downstream VIP. In my sendmail.mc file, I have:

```
define(`SMART_HOST',`relay:[vip.example.local]')dnl
```

My understanding is that because the value is enclosed in brackets, sendmail will perform a DNS query and send to the A record that is returned.

I want to have sendmail query the MX record instead. What is the appropriate syntax for that?

Based on the prior post, I suspect that it should be:

```
define(`SMART_HOST',`vip.example.local')dnl
```

but I'm not sure if the `RELAY:` reference is needed.

Answer (score 2):

```
define(`SMART_HOST',`relay:[vip.example.local]')dnl
```

Square brackets in above sendmail config disable looking for `MX` records first, sendmail goes straight to looking for `A`/`AAAA` records.

`relay:` prefix selects mailer sendmail uses to send to host(s) listed after prefix.  SMTP based `relay` mailer is used by default anyway => usually `relay:` prefix may be skipped. Keeping it makes difference only in some "unusual" situations.
*[technicalities: sendmail ignores "naked" relays with names listed in `$=w`, some people modify `relay` mailer to use it for sending to non standard port also on localhost]*

So you should use `vip.example.local` (no square brackets, no mailer) to make sendmail look for `MX` records of `vip.example.local` and use them if present.

```
define(`SMART_HOST',`vip.example.local')dnl
```

Comment: So technically, would ``define(`SMART_HOST',`relay:vip.example.local')dnl`` work (with the relay part added)?

Comment: `relay:vip.example.local` selects `relay` mailer explicitly. `vip.example.local` selects `relay` mailer implicitly **UNLESS** other sendmail options change "default" mailer to another mailer.  Sendmail configuration can be simple but sky is the limit for possible complexity :-)

Comment: But if I'm already using the `relay` mailer for the original syntax, why would I potentially not want to use it for the modified smarthost? Sorry I guess I'm not familiar with what exactly a mailer does.

Comment: Both versions are **almost** the same.  There is no difference in most of typical configurations, there are subtle differences in non typical situations or configurations.  I personally recommend version without relay mailer but it is a matter of preferred "style-guide".  It does not achieve level "right versus wrong" difference.